# LAG EXTRACT from Golden Gate through API

Tags: oracle, integration, oracle-golden-gate

Is there any way to [extract lag](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/ggsci_commands012.htm#GWURF156) from Golden Gate Database in other way than using ssh client (GGSCI)? I need to integrate it with java application and I'm looking for the fastest and the most efficient sollution. I've only found the one way [to do that](https://tinky2jed.wordpress.com/technical-stuff/oracle-stuff/oracle-goldengate-replication-latency-reporting/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write a Unix script for this and run a cron job for every 1 hour or whatever time period you require?

For example:

1. Create a script on the GG server set login id and password
2. Do info all >> to a .txt file
3. So now you will have 5 columns make it $1- $5
4. If I'm not wrong $4 will be your lag column.
5. Echo that and set the way you need the body for the alert and send it

Let me know you need any help on this.